# swagger api key in header

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger codegen to create C# code to use as a client api call.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://testing.com/swagger/docs/v1 -c config.json -l csharp -o testing-api
```

config.json:

```
{
  "modelPropertyNaming": "PascalCase",
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "apiKey": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "description": "API Key Authentication",
      "name": "X-Key",
      "in": "header"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I call the api using the generated c# code:

```
var apiInstance = new EventApi();
var testRequest = new TestRequest(); 

apiInstance.TestSendEvent(testRequest );
```

How can I add spi key in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this, and it works:

```
apiInstance.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-Key", "12345");
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling your API through http? If thats the case, you can add your key to the authorization header of the http request.

Comment: swagger-codegen will generate something like sdk to call api using http.